# ionic 2.1 - Native scrolling not working with ion-tabs

Tags: ionic-framework

Im trying to use native scroll in my app, inside :

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab>
         <ion-content>
            <messages-directive></messages-directive>
         </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab>
         <ion-content>
         </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I'm testing the code on Galaxy S4 android version 4.4.2

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in release [1.2.4](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases/tag/v1.2.4) of ionic framework, please update your ionic.

- [Github Issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4891)
- [Commit fix](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/1f2178f3c797ab37b7e68c3f0bda058656a197f6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css, you can put the elements into a div a use this:

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

If you want control the scroll in layout, change the overflow: scroll to overflow-x: auto; or overflow-y: auto;

Comment: Hi, the idea was to use the native scroll of each mobile using <ion-content> and not by adding custom css. thanks

Comment: Have you tried this :   <ion-scroll direction="xy" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
 </ion-scroll>  ?????

Comment: from ionic docs: If you’d just like to have a center content scrolling area, use ionContent instead.